# Directive Inside ngRepeat Doesn't Update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get a custom directive to work inside of ngRepeat, but can't get the obvious to work. In this case I don't 'believe' I want to isolate scope. I suspect this is simply a matter of framework ignorance, but can't seem to figure it out. I have a plunk here to show: http://plnkr.co/edit/LNGJHtbh7Ay0CYzebcwr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link` function runs only once for each instance of the `sel` directive, so it renders the `arr.name` value one time. In order to make it aware of future changes, you can use a `$watch`:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attr){
  scope.$watch('arr.name', function() {
    elm.text(scope.arr.name)
  });
}
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHX9GEKfaDEnlBzHRB9U?p=preview).

You can find more information on that in the [$rootScope documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I will re-read root scope. I had tried a watch before, but had been using 'scope.arr'. Thanks again for the help.